# Jest test user registration when bcrypting the password

Tags: react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I'm writting a test for a service which registers users on an app (This is a test app so security is not an issue :)) and I'm doing user password hashing etc in FE.

Using Jest + Enzyme as my testing frameworks.

Here is a test:

```
test('Registering users work as expected', async () => {
    let user = {username: 'jestUser', password: 'jestUser'};

    await expect(UserService._registerNewUser(user)).resolves.toEqual({
        validated: true,
        reason: 'You have successfully registered !',
        user: {
            password: '$2a$10$Hwzm25j2w47Du6yPDslB7OnY/YVurYjm9paMZg8MeaN34bO2FkHmS',
            username: 'jestUser'
        }
    });
})
```

The problem is resolved password is always different because of salts + bcrypt, so my tests fail.

What would be the best way to test this? Is there a way to test returned object and exclude password from checking? Or have some sort of length check?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after some time and reading documentation I managed to solve the issue :)

Correct test function looks like this:

```
test('Registering users work as expected', async () => {
    let user = {username: 'jestUser', password: 'jestUser'};

    await expect(UserService._registerNewUser(user)).resolves.toEqual({
        validated: true,
        reason: 'You have successfully registered !',
        user: {
            password: expect.anything(),
            username: 'jestUser'
        }
    });
})
```

You can make 'password' to expect anything if its value is changing.

Hope this saves some time for someone else in the future :)

Comment: You could also do `expect.not.stringMatching("yourpassword")` to at least ensure it's not stored in plain text.